# Unable to install steam on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, steam

I am trying to install steam via command line, it gives this error:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

On trying `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` I get:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed or
                            libgl1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

and on trying `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` I get

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: added the full error message of `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

EDIT: Also, when I launch steam and it won't open its normal way, it gives this error: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libX11.so.6"

Comment: @Kulfy this leads to "  Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libgl1-mesa-dri'?
Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libgl1-mesa-glx'?  "

Comment: @Kulfy yes I tried to install i386 , but it gave an error, hence not installed. Steam wasn't installed, it gave the same error

Comment: Hello @Kulfy, I thank you for your help. The problem is now solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam has a dependency on

```
libgl1-mesa-glx and libgl1-mesa-dri
```

which depend on libgbm1, hence installing this properly and running 
`sudo apt install steam` installed steam properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the i386 architecture.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then do updates/upgrades:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And possibly fix any missing packages

```
sudo apt install --fix-missing
```

You should now be able to install steam.

Comment: I am still unable to install steam :( . It leads to same error of 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:' sudo apt upgrade leads to nothing, but throws this: "The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri"

Comment: Also, when I launch steam and it won't open its normal way, it gives this error: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libX11.so.6"

Comment: Hello @Joshua, I was able to solve my problem, steam is now working fine!

Comment: glad you got it working... was it the "fix missing" thing that finally did it?

Comment: Probably, due to some reason libgbm1 was holding the update of other dependencies back. Updated that and steam installed fine(but now I've fallen in another problem, lol)

Answer (score 0):

I have to start saying i never had any problem with 32bit drivers and steam, this said, you can add 32bit compatibility by executing:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then apt-get update

if any broken package, try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

if no result:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install -f #-f means fix
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should fix broken packages and update & upgrade.

Try reinstalling steam next using its `.deb` from their website

Comment: It leads to same error of 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:' sudo apt upgrade gives this:"The following packages have been kept back: libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri"

Comment: Also, when I launch steam and it won't open its normal way, it gives this error: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libX11.so.6"

Comment: Hello @Juan, somehow I was able to solve the problem. I thank you for your help!

Comment: to the ones who couldnt fix it: how about using NOT mesa drivers, and using a dedicated driver like nvidia or amd? mesa are just generic, and pretty terrible. Does it job but thats it, no power.

Comment: I would, but unfortunately there isn't a driver for my graphics card(and r5 m430). I have to use oibaf's drivers or integrated one